# I want to add Used space column in my powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I want to make some changes to below script .

```
 try{
$space = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk `
| Format-Table DeviceID,`
 @{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.size/1gb))}}, `
 @{Name="Free Space(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.freespace/1gb))}}, `
@{Name="Free (%)";Expression={"{0,6:P0}" -f(($_.freespace/1gb) / ($_.size/1gb))}} `
-AutoSize
}
catch 
{
echo "Exception Occurred. Please try again on $servername"
}

echo "The total space on $servername are given below:"
echo $space
```

I want to add a column which shows used space without any changes to output format.

output is below:

```
The total space on  are given below:

DeviceID Size(GB) Free Space(GB) Free (%)
-------- -------- -------------- --------
A:              0              0         
C:             60             41   69 %  
D:            100             78   78 %  
E:            200            190   95 %  
G:              0              0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself,refer to below code:

```
$servername = hostname

#checking for disk space
try{
$space = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk `
| Format-Table DeviceID,`
 @{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.size/1gb))}}, `
 @{Name="Free Space(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.freespace/1gb))}}, `
 @{Name="Used Space(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f(($_.size/1gb) - ($_.freespace/1gb)))}}, `
@{Name="Free (%)";Expression={"{0,6:P0}" -f(($_.freespace/1gb) / ($_.size/1gb))}} `
-AutoSize
}
catch 
{
echo "Exception Occurred. Please try again on $servername"
}

echo "The total space on $servername are given below:"
echo $space
```

The desired result required was :

```
The total space on sw02014 are given below:

DeviceID Size(GB) Free Space(GB) Used Space(GB) Free (%)
-------- -------- -------------- -------------- --------
A:              0              0              0         
C:             60             41             18   69 %  
D:            100             78             22   78 %  
E:            200            190             10   95 %  
G:              0              0              0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the table as follows

```
try
{
    $space = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceID,
    @{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.size/1gb))}},
    @{Name="Free Space(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.freespace/1gb))}},
    @{Name="Free (%)";Expression={"{0,6:P0}" -f(($_.freespace/1gb) / ($_.size/1gb))}},
    @{Name="Used Space(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.size/1gb - $_.freespace/1gb))}},
    @{Name="Used Space (%)";Expression={"{0,6:P0}" -f(($_.size/1gb - $_.freespace/1gb) / ($_.size/1gb))}}
    -AutoSize
}
catch 
{
    echo "Exception Occurred. Please try again on $servername"
}

echo "The total space on $servername are given below:"
echo $space
```

Comment: thanks for answer I figured it out , posted the answer below just 10 seconds ago.

Comment: After adding my answer I saw that you already posted a possible solution.